# Update for JavaEE application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Our application are built on Spring boot, the app will be packaged to a `war` file and ran with `java -jar xx.war -Dspring.profile=xxx`. Generally the latest `war` package will served by  a static web server like nginx.

Now we want to know if we can add auto-update for the application.

I have googled, and people suggested to  use the Application server which support hot deployment, however we use spring boot as shown above.

I have thought to start a new thread once my application started, then check update and download the latest package. But I have to terminate the current application to start the new one since they use the same port, and if close the current app, the update thread will be terminated too.

So how to you handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion that should be managed by some higher order dev-ops level orchestration system not by either the app nor its container.  The decision to replace an app should not be at the dev-ops level and not the app level

One major advantage of spring-boot is the inversion of the traditional application-web-container to web-app model.  As such the web container is usually (and best practice with Spring boot) built within the app itself.  Hence it is fully self contained and crucially immutable.  It therefore should not be the role of the app-web-container/web-app to replace either part-of or all-of itself.

Of course you can do whatever you like but you might find that the solution is not easy because it is not convention to do it in this way.